# Is there a single word meaning "the thing that attracts me"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a single word meaning "the thing that attracts me"?

The terms *attractor* or *drawer* don't feel right:

> *The attractor for me at this restaurant is their sumptuous ravioli.*

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The **allure** for me at this restaurant is their sumptuous ravioli.

allure  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/allurement)

n.

> The power to attract; enticement.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the word I was after.

Comment: Ravioli may *have* an allure, but I don't think it *is* an allure...

Comment: @usul This usage works fine for me, maybe a bit weird

Comment: It's weird because it's almost always used as an adjective, sometimes as a verb, and rarely as a noun.

Comment: Possibly even just [*lure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lure) (the noun). Probably focuses on the attractive force rather than the thing which exudes it.

Comment: @Mazura There exists an adjective *allure?* Not on [M-W.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allure) (Maybe the verb is often used as a past participle, as in the examples there.)

Answer (score 50):

The **appeal** maybe? "To me, the appeal of this restaurant is their sumptuous ravioli."

---

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appeal): "the quality in someone or something that makes him, her, or it attractive or interesting:"

- sex appeal
- Spielberg's movies have a wide appeal.
- This used to be a marvellous hotel but it has lost its appeal in recent years.

Comment: Hi, Erwan. Could you supply quotes and attributed references ... answers on ELU are preferred when supported by such, even when they're quite obviously correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sure, added a definition with examples

Comment: Thank you. 'ELU expects' and all that :)

Answer (score 37):

I think you're going for "attraction" which is the noun form of attract. But the sentence is still a little stilted. "Draw" would be nice - "The draw for me at this restaurant is the sumptuous ravioli."

Comment: +1 Yes, but: The attraction for me of this x

Comment: The ```draw``` is right. ```drawer``` felt so weird, I knew I was missing something.

Comment: @Siddhartha An easy mstake to make but a "drawer" is sliding part of a piece of furniture, very occasionally a graphic artist or, even less frequently, someone who pulls raffle tickets from a hat or water from well. A "draw" is an attraction.

Comment: Hi, Jane. Could you supply quotes and attributed references ... answers on ELU are preferred when supported by such, even when they're quite obviously correct.

Comment: Perhaps [main attraction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499235/73987) is more natural?

Answer (score 8):

Enticing? It may be worth using a thesaurus here to get a list of suitable words.

> I was enticed to the restaurant by their delicious ravioli.

Comment: Probably "Enticement" is the form they need, but good answer

Answer (score 5):

The word **magnet** is often used metaphorically, and is probably usually one of the most natural-sounding of the set of synonyms:

> **magnet** noun ...
>
> 1.1 A person or thing that has a powerful attraction.
>
> *‘the beautiful stretch of white sand is a magnet for sun-worshippers’*
>
> {[**ODO**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/magnet)}

However, I'd have to re-arrange OP's example to 'The sumptuous ravioli is a magnet for many people at this restaurant.'

*Crowd-puller, main attraction, inducement* and *lure* are synonyms that may work on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

I think "draw card" is probably the closest common phrase. "[Drawcard](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drawcard)" if you want a single world. Dictionary definition:

> a quality or feature that evokes interest or liking; an attraction.

In this case one might say

> For me, the draw card of [xyz restaurant] is their sumptuous ravioli.

By itself "draw card" would, in my experience, suggest that people in general would find it attractive, so qualifying it as a "personal draw card" would specify that it's *your* favourite dish.

Comment: Hi, Artelius. Could you supply quotes and attributed references ... answers on ELU are preferred when supported by such, even when they're quite obviously correct. And I agree, your answer sounds more natural than most others, so +1.

Comment: Good thinking - good answer

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a colorful word, you could use also [*catnip*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catnip):

> Someone or something that is very attractive or appealing to a particular person or group.

e.g. For me, this restaurant's sumptuous ravioli is just catnip.

Comment: This is taking metaphor to absurd lengths...

Comment: @smci: I've seen/heard it used.

Comment: well not outside the rhetorical flourishes of restaurant reviewers, in everyday speech...?

Comment: In my universe, if people call a restaurant's food catnip, the health inspectors might get called in... (yes, though not 'catfood')

Answer (score 0):

When there may be more than one thing that is attractive but we want to point out the *most* attractive thing, we often use **main attraction**:

> The main attraction at Yellowstone Park is Old Faithful. ([Oxford
>   US](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/attraction)) 
>  The main attraction at Giverny is Monet's garden.
>   ([Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attraction))

I think that would work well here too:

***The main attraction for me at this restaurant is their sumptuous ravioli.***

Comment: I suppose you could also use pièce de résistance

Comment: @micahhoover : "pièce de résistance" doesn't remind me of anything in French. closest match is "plat de résistance", which just mean the main meal, and says nothing about the appeal one of the menu option has on the speaker.

Comment: "attraction" works for Yellowstone or Giverny because it may mean "An entertainment that is offered to the public" [https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=attraction] , which obviously doesn't work for Raviolis.

Comment: @sylvainulg Old Faithful isn't "entertainment" either, other than in a very loose definition of the word that would also work for ravioli. I would just say that the reason attraction *can* work for ravioli is that it's something that attracts :)

Answer (score 0):

The single word for "the thing that attracts" (as opposed to describing the attraction itself) is:

**Attractant**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attractant

Most examples of this word usage are for the chemical substance produced by insects to attract each other: however it may be used in a general sense also.